# writing code that supports new and older c++ compilers?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to write a code that can support newer and older compilers and i was wondering before i start is something like this possible?

```
#ifndef C++11 { //some code..... } 
#endif 

else 

#ifndef older C++ version { //some code......}
#endif
```

Comment: You _can_ probably do something like that, but it's probably easier to just restrict your code to the parts of the language (and standard library) that didn't change significantly.

Comment: If you want to support "older compilers", why not just write C++98 in the first place?

Comment: thanks, i'm working on project on a system with gcc 3.4.X version compiler i.e a very old cluster , i installed a gentoo prefix on it with the newest gcc 4.6.2 , and wanted to test new things and make sure they worked for the old system as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard requires C++11 conforming implementations to define a macro named `__cplusplus` to the value `201103L`. Nonconforming compilers are recommended to use a value with at most five decimal digits. The same was true for C++03 where the value this should be defined to is `199711L`.

However, not many compilers consider(ed) themselves standards compliant, and e.g. gcc defined this for a long time to be just `1L`. Also you have to consider that it is not only the compiler version, but also the parameters to the compiler. Gcc only supports (part of) C++11 when you pass `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`. In these cases it will define a macro `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`.

So the most portable solution is to be unportable and have your own macro that you set when C++11 support is detected, and have some header/configure script in which you use the aforementioned things, along with possibly others for other supported compilers.

Answer (score 3):

There's no simple universal macro, and for most compilers, it's not a binary "yes or no". Most compilers implement *some* C++11 features, but certainly not all.

MSVC simply has a single `_MSC_VER` macro indicating the version of the compiler, and if *you* know which features are supported by which version, then you can use that.

Clang has pretty comprehensive feature-specific macros, of the form `_HAS_<feature>` (I can't remember if that's the precise name).

If you want to know, across all compilers, whether feature X is available, you'll have to check all these different macros and determine the answer yourself. :)

Answer (score 1):

In MSVS you have the macro, `_MSC_VER` which can help you. I don't know if there's such a standard macro.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standards committee spent a lot of effort to make sure, that any code written to the older standard is still valid in the new standard. And if you have to do without a feature on some platforms, using it on the others is a lot of work for rarely any gain. So just stick to the older version you need to support.

For the few exceptions the most reliable way is to test the compiler and define macros to choose the version you want to use. Either manually if you know your set of compilers or using something like autoconf or cmake if you don't. There are many compilers that support some C++11 features and not others, so there's little hope to find some test that would suffice without any work on your part. I believe all the features can be tested with just compiling; if they compile, they will generally also work.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code to be compliant with the most recent compiler.

Any code which won't compile against an older version should be extracted into its own .cpp unit.

Then an alternative .cpp should be written for the old compiler.

For older builds select to include the older .cpp.

You don't need #defines.

See [#ifdef Considered Harmful](http://static.usenix.org/publications/library/proceedings/sa92/spencer.pdf)